# I am scraping a webpage and i want to separate a part of the text in the 'script' section

Tags: python, html, url, python-requests

I am making a request for a webpage. The webpage is redirecting me to another webpage. I want to extract this website from the response and convert it to a string.

```
    response = requests.get(url_broker,allow_redirects=False)
    #print(response)
    soup_ref = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    
    #print(soup_ref)
    #data = json.loads(soup_ref.find('script', type='application/ld+json').text)
    all_scripts = soup_ref.find_all('script')
    #print(all_scripts[0])
    all_scripts[1]
```

[See the image with the result of all_scripts[1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAfLU.png)

I want to extract the specific website url that is visible in this image and placed somewhere in the script under ['link']['url'] --> https:// .... etc. How would i be able to convert the url into a string so that i can use it later in my python program?

i tried to apply all sorts of methods and fuctions on all_scripts[1] but I couldnt extract any text.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and instead of the image paste the HTML code as text (with correct formatting)?